# My Scheme Function: How to Make it Recursive

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

So in my scheme function, provided below, I need to produce a list of structures. So far, I've made 2 helper functions: One calls a list of numbers counting up from 1 to x. The other calls the structure that corresponds to x.

For example:

```
(helper1 10) -> (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

(helper2 1) -> (make-person 0 1) 

(helper2 2) -> (make-person 1 2) 

(helper2 3) -> (make-person 2 3) etc...
```

How can I make my main function call the list of helper1, where each element is replaced with its corresponding structure.

Note: My main function must be recursive, and it must produce a list of structures.

So far, for my main function I have:

```
(define (main-function x)
 (cond
 [(zero? x) empty]
  [else 
     ...]))
```

Also, I am writing in Beginner Student with List Abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to construct an entirely new list, not replace each element with a structure. That's the appearance of the end result, but not how the function works.

Basically, if your `main-function` takes in a number, then you'll want to create a helper function that actually does the recursion, where you will pass in the result of calling `(helper1 x)`.

Then, in your recursion, you're just recontructing a list with the corresponding structures.

```
(define (main-function x)
  (main-function-helper (helper1 x)))

(define (main-function-helper l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) l]
    [else (cons (helper2 (first l))
                (main-function-helper (rest l)))]))
```

---

Another option that may make more sense is to never create the intermediate list:

```
(define (main-function x)
  (main-function-helper 1 x))

(define (main-function-helper counter max)
  (cond
    [(= counter max) (cons (helper2 counter) empty)]
    [else (cons (helper2 counter)
                (main-function-helper (add1 counter) max))]))
```